# selenium issue: with selecting a value in dropdown using thymeleaf

Tags: selenium, testing, drop-down-menu, thymeleaf

I am facing an issue selecting a value inside a dropdown during a selenium test. I am getting my values from a properties file using thymeleaf in the following way.

```
<option th:each="medication : ${medications}"
        th:id="${medication.key}"
        th:value="${medication.value.fplPercent}"
        th:text="${medication.value.name}">
</option>
```

When I try to select a value in the dropdown, selenium is not able to do that. Instead of getting the dropdown values from properties file using thymeleaf, if I give all my options in the html file(like below), selenium is able to select  a value from the dropdown with out any problem.

```
<option id="A" value="300">Ibuprofuen</option>
<option id="B" value="300">Tylenol</option>
<option id="C" value="300">Beatblocker</option>
```

I know how I get the values populated in the dropdown is causing me problems. Please advise me on how to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: When you view the source of your thymeleaf page in a browser, how does it differ from the html example you have above?

Comment: @Metroids : Thanks for your question. I verified both ways in the view source in browser and they look the same way. Please let me know if I can add more details to my question here.

Comment: @JeffC: Please let me know if I am missing something here. Thanks

Comment: If the html looks the same, then the error is probably somewhere else (and we probably can't find it without more details).  Perhaps the id or name of the `<select>` element is different.

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? You haven't posted any of your code attempts. It's hard to tell what you are doing wrong if we can see what you've done. The elements you've posted all have IDs... surely you can use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the solution. I tried using an Action class to click on a particular value in the drop-down and it worked. Please see below code.

I am getting the element:

```
WebElement productOne = findElementById("A");
```

and Earlier I was using click() function to select the product

```
productOne.click();
```

But Now I tried using Action class Click function in the following way

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(productOne).click().build().perform();
```

and it was able to select the value and my test passed. Thanks to @Metroids and @JeffC for the contributions.

NOTE: I am still not sure why selecting a value from dropdown using the normal click function is not working and if thymeleaf has to do anything here.